# Addition with decimal React Native doesnt return number

Tags: javascript, react-native, addition

I am in a project building simple mathematic app with react native. but when my input is added with decimal number, it doesnt sum, but it just merge

```
var height = 56
const convertHeight = height+0.7
```

it return 560.7, instead of 56.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var height = 56
const convertHeight = height*1.0+0.7
```

Comment: I dont know how to express man. solved. Javascript is funnier than my father

Comment: x1 Is ultimate trick, for every thing else, thanks javascript https://res.cloudinary.com/practicaldev/image/fetch/s--_LM23l-b--/c_limit%2Cf_auto%2Cfl_progressive%2Cq_auto%2Cw_880/https://thepracticaldev.s3.amazonaws.com/i/a2k7x6ghilt6hp5mhgd7.png